# What is the purpose of WinRT's IStorageFolder interface?

Tags: interface, windows-runtime, storagefolder

Since WinRT exposes both the `IStorageFolder` interface and the `StorageFolder` class, my reflex was to use the interface throughout my code. I reasoned that `IStorageFolder` could be used as an abstraction to support non-filesystem folders like those in compressed archives. However, looking at the `IStorageFolder` interface, every method is declared to return concrete `StorageFolder` instances. As such, it would not be possible to implement a virtual filesystem based on this interface.

So how is `IStorageFolder` a useful abstraction? Or does its existence have a technical justification?

Comment: All the new-style COM classes have matching interfaces (you can verify this by opening Windows.winmd with ildasm), so I'd venture the guess that this one just happens to be exposed.

Comment: @zneak I thought it might be a COM thing but hadn't realized it was so generalized. It does seem a bit random which of those interfaces are exposed. I guess the conclusion is that there's no point in using the interfaces. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an interface because there are two implementations of `IStorageFolder`: One is [`StorageFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx), and another is [`FolderInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.bulkaccess.folderinformation.aspx). Since there are two implementations, the common behavior uses an interface so that you can write a function that operates on either `StorageFolder` or `FolderInformation`.